Solucionar el error : Chart.js ->> Failed to create chart: can't acquire context from the given item
Estoy intentando usar Chart.js para generar un grafico y obtengo siempre: Failed to create chart: can't acquire context from the given item
Mi aplicación está casi toda en javascript y utilizamos funciones como esta para mostrar datos:
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>


    function getTablaCuestPrestaciones(){
    var tabla = document.createElement('table');
    tabla.className = 'inicio';
        var div = document.createElement('div');
            var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            canvas.id = "grafica";
            canvas.style.width = "807";
            canvas.style.height = "402";
        div.appendChild(canvas);        
    tabla.appendChild(div);     
    return tabla;
}[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]

// script.js ---->
const $grafica = document.querySelector("#grafica");
const etiquetas = ["Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril"]
const datosVentas2020 = {
    label: "Ventas por mes",
    data: [5000, 1500, 8000, 5102],   
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',  
    borderColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',  
    borderWidth: 1
};
new Chart($grafica, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: etiquetas,
        datasets: [
            datosVentas2020
        ]
    }
   
});



Deberías agregar el código HTML para que sea mas completa tu pregunta, ya que la imagen no la ven algunos usuarios.

A mi me suena que es un error por el orden de ejecución. Puede que primero se esté intentando crear el chart (todavia no se ejecuto getTablaCuestPrestaciones) y posteriormente el canvas

genial era problema del orden. gracias
